# Java Socket ] instance of DataInputStream is print continue null

Tags: java, sockets, datainputstream

I'm making Chatting-Room program using the Java Swing.

In the client side, I was saw that doesn't read message from the server side.

The `writeUTF()` method of the client side is very well and I'm checked `readUTF` and `writeUTF` on the server side, that was very well too.

I think the problem is code which does as "Receiver" on the client side.

In the `run()` method of Thread, The instance `dis` of the `DataInputStream` has continuously null value.

I'm so confusing.. Please give me some help.

The bellow is part of my client&server code.

Thanks!

**Client code**

**RoomBackground.java**

```
public class RoomBackground {

    private static String socket_server = "127.0.0.1";
    private static Socket chatSocket;
    private static DataOutputStream dos;
    private static DataInputStream dis;
    private ChatReceiver chatReceiver;

    public Socket getChatSocket() {
        return chatSocket;
    }

    public static DataOutputStream getDos() {
        return dos;
    }

    public RoomBackground() throws IOException {
        chatSocket = new Socket(socket_server, 7777);
        chatReceiver = new ChatReceiver();
        chatReceiver.start();

        dos = new DataOutputStream(chatSocket.getOutputStream());
        dis = new DataInputStream(chatSocket.getInputStream());
        dos.writeUTF(User.getUser().getUsername());
        dos.flush();
    }
    class ChatReceiver extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run(){
            try {
                # PROBLEM CODE..... Allways "dis is null"
                System.out.println("dis is " + dis);

                # This line never executed.
                while(dis != null) {    

                    # some codes.....

                }  
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println(e.toString());
            } catch (BadLocationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**RoomFrame.java**

```
public class RoomFrame extends JFrame{

    private RoomBackground roomBackground;

    public RoomFrame(int roomId) throws IOException {
        chatField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            roomBackground  = new RoomBackground();
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String msg = chatField.getText() + "\n";
                try {
                    RoomBackground.getDos().writeUTF(msg);

                    # It works.
                    System.out.println("sent msg is " + msg);
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                chatField.setText("");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Now server code.**

**Server Background.java**

```
public class ChatReceiver extends Thread {

    private DataInputStream in;
    private DataOutputStream out;

    public ChatReceiver(Socket chatSocket) throws IOException {

        out = new DataOutputStream(chatSocket.getOutputStream());
        in = new DataInputStream(chatSocket.getInputStream());

        nick = in.readUTF();
        addChatClient(nick, out);    
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while(in!=null) {
                chatMsg = in.readUTF();

                # It works !
                System.out.println("before send" + chatMsg);
                sendMsg(chatMsg);

                # It works too!
                System.out.println("after send" + chatMsg);
            }
        }catch (IOException e) {
            removeChatClient(nick);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are starting the `ChatReceiver` thread in the `RoomBackground` the `dis` object is not initialized yet, that is why it is `null`. One solution could be to initialize the `dis` variable in the `ChatReceiver` constructor.